# Flutter iOS Simulation keep having failed Xcode build

Tags: flutter

Just installed Flutter but Flutter keep failing to open up a fresh project in iOS Simulator

Error in Terminal

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         2.2s
Xcode build done.                                           16.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: unknown option: -target
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

Tried Flutter Clean but it doesn't work.

I ran Flutter Doctor but everything seems fine.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Please help.

Update 1 Aug
Ran flutter run -v and here's the result. Still I can't start the file from flutter run. However, Xcode could build and run the file fine. Same goes to Android Studio.

```
[  +37 ms] Failed to build iOS app
[        ] Error output from Xcode build:
           ↳
[        ]     ** BUILD FAILED **
           
           
               The following build commands failed:
                Ld

/Users/jason/Develop/first/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runne
                r normal x86_64
               (1 failure)
           
[        ] Xcode's output:
           ↳
[  +56 ms]     Command line invocation:
                   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
                   -configuration Debug VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES -workspace
                   Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
                   BUILD_DIR=/Users/jason/Develop/first/build/ios -sdk
iphonesimulator
                   -arch x86_64

SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/1n/fywsxx0j35g060rtr5b9ff9c0000gn
                   /T/flutter_build_log_pipe.KUbRcA/pipe_to_stdout
                   FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true
COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
           
               Build settings from command line:
                   ARCHS = x86_64
                   BUILD_DIR = /Users/jason/Develop/first/build/ios
                   COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
                   FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS = true
                   SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE =

/var/folders/1n/fywsxx0j35g060rtr5b9ff9c0000gn/T/flutter_build_log_pipe.
                   KUbRcA/pipe_to_stdout
                   SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.6
                   VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING = YES
           
               note: Using new build system
               note: Building targets in parallel
               note: Planning build
               note: Constructing build description
               ProcessProductPackaging ""
```

Anyone got any clue what's happening?

Comment: So I ran the iOS portion of Flutter code with Xcode and it did run on the Simulator! (fresh created Flutter app). However, I still can't get it to run with flutter run on Terminal, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I can't figure out why. Wiped my HD and reinstalled macOS Catalina, Xcode and now it works.